# Typescript dynamic getter/setter

Tags: typescript, accessor

I'm stuck trying to make Typescript infer types of dynamically created getter and setter. I have a class `MyClass` with `containers` map:

```
type Container = {
    get: () => Content
    set: (value: Content) => void
}

type ContainersMap = { [key: string]: Container }

class MyClass {
    containers: ContainersMap

    constructor(names: string[]) {
        this.containers = {} as ContainersMap

        names.forEach(name => {
            Object.defineProperty(this.containers, name, {
                get() { return read(name) },
                set(value) { write(name, value) }
            })
        })

        Object.freeze(this.containers)
    }
}
```

And next in my code I want to use it like this:

```
let someContent: Content = {/* some content */}

let myClass = new MyClass(['first', 'second'])

// Getting type error in line below because TS thinks I try assign Content to Container
myClass.containers['first'] = someContent
```

A possible solution I found is to define `type ContainersMap = { [key: string]: Content }` but I dislike this solution because in my opinion it doesn't reflect the actual `ContainersMap` type

Is it a way to implement this properly?

Comment: `{ [key: string]: Container }` means that each key of `this.containers` is an object with `get` and `set` methods rather than a property that you can set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think about the public interface of the class separately from the implementation details.

```
type Container = {
    get: () => Content
    set: (value: Content) => void
}
```

This type defines an object with properties `get` and `set`.  It means that you can call `myClass.containers.first.set(someContent)`.  But you cannot do `myClass.containers.first = someContent` because `myClass.containers.first` is supposed to be of type `Container`, not of type `Content`.

The `get` and `set` methods should be just an implementation detail.  They are the way that your class implements the interface that you want -- which is for `myClass.containers.first` to be a readable and writable property of type `Content`.  The public "contract" of that interface is very simple.

```
type ContainersMap = { [key: string]: Content }
```

or with a known set of keys:

```
type ContainersMap<K extends string> = { [key in K]: Content } // same as Record<K, Content>
```

Since there is no initial value, you might want to make the properties optional.

---

You will need a generic class in order for the `ContainersMap` to know about your specific keys.  I'm not sure what the `read` and `write` methods are in your code so I'm just leaving them be. This is basically what you want:

```
class MyClass<K extends string> {
    containers: ContainersMap<K>

    constructor(names: K[]) {
        this.containers = {} as ContainersMap<K>

        names.forEach(name => {
            Object.defineProperty(this.containers, name, {
                get() { return read(name) },
                set(value) { write(name, value) }
            })
        })

        Object.freeze(this.containers)
    }
}
```

You do not need the type `Container` at all anymore.

---

This allows you to get and set known properties:

```
let myClass = new MyClass(['first', 'second'])

myClass.containers.first = someContent;

console.log(myClass.containers.first);
```

But you cannot access other properties:

```
// Error: Property 'third' does not exist on type 'ContainersMap<"first" | "second">'
myClass.containers.third = someContent;
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtwXMg3gWAChkTkA3OAGwC5kBnMKUAcwG4iBfIosATwAcUGcHFDQ6AWTj8APAGlkEAB6QQAEzr1GLAHzIAvHmQBtANYReyUMjkBdWsNVhkXQkQSU4dTRN6pP3vKKKtgaWkwgzHoExKQImGCiIOIOCUniUrJyOtyxJPEgDFAArghg6FAAFCBwALYQdLRyxrYAlHhEpF3IYAAWwHQAdAWJYlCahrgcyF5oaWOS0vI5bnndNfVDMBUAooi91XUo%20tGd3ecA8gBGAFYQZYNqEDBiAApQ6IJQfJV9A8PzZLjAA0yA2EFBMXO0NIzAgYEq7VwyCg8OKUBAKIgcDUh3q7Q4wLOMPOdHhlQolGKECRyAA7kxIHiIeQqNSCcSSRxWpyutzcjDrncHjBURAAF4QX79IYjdLjHlrVyuIiUeH0dD1RzYMCpLA4SasmjIADkJpcuTVzlqfgCEzBEDpyF8-i8dEqxhNL3GYBNoJNZIKahNbVyNtd3gBIgWg29DAMGq1CR17FWBTo6DVg0o6GYlXDdqjoyBdFaqaIBbdRflQz%20UDUCYzSf1YFYQA)

Comment: So the main conclusion I can do is that definition `type ContainersMap = { [key: string]: Content }` is ok because getter and setter is about internal `ContainersMap` implementation and it doesn't matter to define them, right?